How to Populate Column Values Based on Conditions in SQL?
I’m trying to explain an interesting scenario I’m facing in SQL. I’m not sure if there’s a specific window function or other keywords to achieve this, but let me explain.
I have a table structured as follows:



COLA
COLB
COLC
COLD
COLE
COLF
COLG
COLH




W12

2023-10-22


12341
G12UYI



W13
W12

COLC

12341
G12UYI



W14
W12

COLC

12341
G12UYI



W15
W12

COLC
2021-10-18
12341
G12UYI



W16
W15

COLE

12341
G12UYI



W17
W15

COLE

12341
G12UYI



W19
W15

COLE

12341
G12UYI



W24




12341
G12UYI
2022-08-25


W45
W24

COLH

12341
G12UYI



W46
W24

COLH

12341
G12UYI



W47
W24

COLH

12341
G12UYI



W48
W24

COLH

12341
G12UYI



W12

2015-10-13


34235
IOP79



W13
W12

COLC

34235
IOP79



W14
W12

COLC

34235
IOP79




Problem:
COLA contains different IDs, which can be repeated for different groups defined by COLF and COLH.
COLB indicates which ID’s value we need to populate in COLJ.
COLD specifies from which column the value should be taken.
For example:
For rows 2 to 4, COLB specifies that we need to populate COLJ with the value from COLC corresponding to W12 in COLA
For rows 5 to 7, we need to take the value corresponding to W15 from COLE.
The value in COLD is limited in the example, but it can many such column name like COLP, COLk etc..
Expected Output:
I need to populate COLJ with the appropriate values based on the conditions set in COLB and COLD.
Expected Output:



COLA
COLB
COLC
COLD
COLE
COLF
COLG
COLH
COLJ




W12

2023-10-22


12341
G12UYI




W13
W12

COLC

12341
G12UYI

2023-10-22


W14
W12

COLC

12341
G12UYI

2023-10-22


W15
W12

COLC
2021-10-18
12341
G12UYI

2023-10-22


W16
W15

COLE

12341
G12UYI

2021-10-18


W17
W15

COLE

12341
G12UYI

2021-10-18


W19
W15

COLE

12341
G12UYI

2021-10-18


W24




12341
G12UYI
2022-08-25



W45
W24

COLH

12341
G12UYI

2022-08-25


W46
W24

COLH

12341
G12UYI

2022-08-25


W47
W24

COLH

12341
G12UYI

2022-08-25


W48
W24

COLH

12341
G12UYI

2022-08-25


W12

2015-10-13


34235
IOP79




W13
W12

COLC

34235
IOP79

2015-10-13


W14
W12

COLC

34235
IOP79

2015-10-13




One option is to create a cte that will collect the data to be used for COLJ:
WITH
  data_source AS
    ( Select      t.COLA, t.COLF, t.COLG, 
                  Case When ds.COL_FROM = 'COLC' Then t.COLC
                       When ds.COL_FROM = 'COLE' Then t.COLE
                       When ds.COL_FROM = 'COLH' Then t.COLH
                  End as COLJ
      From        ( Select Distinct COLB, COLF, COLG, COLD as COL_FROM
                     From   tbl
                     Where  COLB Is Not Null
                   ) ds 
      Inner Join  tbl t ON( t.COLA = ds.COLB And 
                            t.COLF = ds.COLF And 
                            t.COLG = ds.COLG )
    )

CTE data_source result:



COLA
COLF
COLG
COLJ




W12
12341
G12UYI
22-OCT-23


W15
12341
G12UYI
18-OCT-21


W24
12341
G12UYI
25-AUG-22


W12
34235
IOP79
13-OCT-15



... Left Join the above CTE to your table and add the COLJ column ...
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT     t.*, ds.COLJ
FROM       tbl t
LEFT JOIN  data_source ds ON( ds.COLA = t.COLB And 
                              ds.COLF = t.COLF And 
                              ds.COLG = t.COLG )
ORDER BY   t.COLF, t.COLA, t.COLG

R e s u l t :



COLA
COLB
COLC
COLD
COLE
COLF
COLG
COLH
COLJ




W12
null
22-OCT-23
null
null
12341
G12UYI
null
null


W13
W12
null
COLC
null
12341
G12UYI
null
22-OCT-23


W14
W12
null
COLC
null
12341
G12UYI
null
22-OCT-23


W15
W12
null
COLC
18-OCT-21
12341
G12UYI
null
22-OCT-23


W16
W15
null
COLE
null
12341
G12UYI
null
18-OCT-21


W17
W15
null
COLE
null
12341
G12UYI
null
18-OCT-21


W19
W15
null
COLE
null
12341
G12UYI
null
18-OCT-21


W24
null
null
null
null
12341
G12UYI
25-AUG-22
null


W45
W24
null
COLH
null
12341
G12UYI
null
25-AUG-22


W46
W24
null
COLH
null
12341
G12UYI
null
25-AUG-22


W47
W24
null
COLH
null
12341
G12UYI
null
25-AUG-22


W48
W24
null
COLH
null
12341
G12UYI
null
25-AUG-22


W12
null
13-OCT-15
null
null
34235
IOP79
null
null


W13
W12
null
COLC
null
34235
IOP79
null
13-OCT-15


W14
W12
null
COLC
null
34235
IOP79
null
13-OCT-15




Thank you for the answer, I forgot to mention one important point here, the value in COLD , can be of any value, not only the columns I given in the example, so basically to can be column COLI, COLP etc...so I don't want to hardcode those values

@GIN The selection list of columns in SQL must be defined fixed in number of columns, names of columns and datatypes of columns. There is no option of defining the list dynamically. That means either hardcodings in SQL or using procedural language ...

You probably know that this is a horrible data model :-)
An old Analytic Function can be used to create a name-value-pair list and then the value is extracted based on the column name like this:
with cte as
 ( -- create a name-value-pair list
   select * from Pack (
     on ( select *
          from test -- only rows with data
          where colc is not null
             or cole is not null  
             or colh is not null
        )
     using
       Delimiter ('&')
       OutputColumn ('x')
       IncludeColumnName ('true') -- name:value
       ColCast('true') 
       TargetColumns ('colC','colE','colH') -- list of column names
       Accumulate('colA','colF','colG')     -- join columns
   ) as dt
 )
select t.*
  ,nvp(x, t.cold, '&', ':')
from test as t 
left join cte 
  on cte.colA = t.colB -- join back 
 and cte.colF = t.colF 
 and cte.colG = t.colG
order by t.colF, t.colG, t.colA
;


Thanks you for the solution, I am going with a partial automation currently, with column names hardcoded, I know this is a horrible model as you said, so let me leave it here..
